# Do I still need to include testflightlib in my iOS app?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight, crashlytics

Now Apple have [moved TestFlight to iTunes Connect](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/update/) do I still need to include testflightlib and call `[TestFlight takeOff]` on start with my app token? The [new instructions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/BetaTestingTheApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH35-SW2) don't mention this.

Additional question: Should I also keep using Crashlytics or is it redundant now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to include your testflight lib and you don't need to call takeOff.

Actually, [apple is already warning people](https://twitter.com/simX/status/552912427369906176) to remove the framework from the projects.

Regarding crashlytics, yes, you should keep it for crashes since Apple still doesn't provide embedded crash reporting with test flight.

For more information about TestFlight [read this excellent article.](http://www.xmcgraw.com/lets-walk-through-the-apple-testflight-experience/)

Comment: `Regarding crashlytics, yes, you should keep it for crashes since Apple still doesn't provide embedded crash reporting with test flight.` According to the [Xcode 6.3 Beta release notes](http://adcdownload.apple.com//Developer_Tools/Xcode_6.3_beta_2/Xcode_6.3_beta_2_Release_Notes.pdf) this should now work.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do anything like this anymore

The only step you need is to upload to iTunes Connect :)